# Php Regular expression, scanning a document to output the rows and values

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

i know you guys are regular expression  masters, im having a difficulty with the regex pattern im using php preg_match_all,

```
$var = "1        CARRYL               CLOYDE          GLADWIN         93 SOESDYKE LINDEN        FARMER             129790657
        1        fdfdfd               CLOYDE          GLADWIN         93 SOESDYKE LINDEN        FARMER             129790657
        1        dfdfdf               CLOYDE          GLADWIN         93 SOESDYKE LINDEN        FARMER             129790657
        1        gfgfgg               CLOYDE          dfdfdfd         93 SOESDYKE LINDEN        FARMER             129790657
";

$regex = "#(\d+) [A-Z]+  [A-Z]+  [A-Z]+ [0-9-A-Z]+  [A-Z]+ (\d+)#";
preg_match_all($regex,$var,$array);

print_r($array);
?>
```

When i execute this script this is the results that im getting.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) )
```

The results that im looking for is  listed below unfortunately i think there is something missing in my expression could u please help.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1        CARRYL               CLOYDE          GLADWIN         93 SOESDYKE LINDEN        FARMER              129790657
            [1] => 1        fdfdfd               CLOYDE          GLADWIN          93 SOESDYKE LINDEN        FARMER             129790657
            [2] => 1        dfdfdf               CLOYDE          GLADWIN          93 SOESDYKE LINDEN        FARMER             129790657
            [2] => 1        gfgfgg               CLOYDE          GLADWIN          93 SOESDYKE LINDEN        FARMER             129790657

        )

)
```

I have a document with a whole list  like what is defined in $var, i would like the regex pattern to scan the document looking for this data, im having a great difficulty, could you please help thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: You are matching only single spaces. You need `\s+` between each group for multiple whitespace. But anyway this looks like CSV data and regex may not be the way to go.  Is the number of spaces always the same between them? Does the last group belong together as `93 SOESDYKE LINDEN`?

Comment: Yes the number of spaces are always the same between them, yes 93 SOESDYKE LINDEN belongs together

Comment: @AntonioLondon, what is the number of spaces between each value. You say they are the same but your example has different lengths of space.

Answer (score 2):

`m` for multiline and `i` for case-insensitive.

```
$regex = "#\d+\s+[A-Z]+\s+[A-Z]+\s+[A-Z]+\s+\d+\s[A-Z]+\s[A-Z]+\s+[A-Z]+\s+\d+#mi";

preg_match_all($regex, $var, $array);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: If this worked for you, you should accept the answer as correct so that future users of the site will know.

Comment: i used this too it worked perfectly $regex = "#(\d+)\s+[A-Z]+\s+[A-Z]+(.*)(\d+){9}#mi";